# Proving $[A][B][C]+[CBA]+[ABC]=[AB][C]+[A][BC]+[AC][B]$ for $2\times 2$ matrices $A$, $B$, $C$, where $[\cdot]$ gives the trace

Tags: linear-algebra

Playing around with matrices, I found a weird trace formula that works for any set of three $2\times 2$ matrices, $A,B,C$:

$$[A][B][C]+[CBA]+[ABC]=[AB][C]+[A][BC]+[AC][B]$$

Let $[A]$ be the trace of a 2x2 matrix.

Other than just brute force, is there a way to prove this identity? Does it have any deeper meaning or is it just a weird quirk? I have not seen this formula before.

Comment: This could be derived from Cayley-Hamilton, see this for some related info: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993372/show-that-texttrxyz-texttryxz-texttrx-texttry-texttrz/3993418#3993418

Comment: @bonsoon The only proof that that answer provides is a hint, and a link to a pdf that allegedly contains the full proof, but you need to register to download it. Which is a shame.

Comment: You should be able to download the pdf with registering, did you try it?

Comment: @bonsoon I might, if I bothered. That's not my point, though. My point is that it's less accessible than it could've been. And link rot is a thing. Relying on outside resources like that is suboptimal for a site like this.